# Background Image shows on Emulator and Real Device Andriod 9.0 but does not show on 8.1 and below

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a xaml page where I set Background Image to some Image and it works good on Emulator(API 27) and Android 9.0 real device. When I deploy the same app to another device (Android 8.1 and 7.0), the background Image does not show in these devices.

I have created a new page and added just the background image property and it turns out the same. Worked well on Android 9.0 and Emulator but not on Android 8.1 and lower versions of android. I have also changed the target framework version of my project to API 27 and the minimum to allow Android 7.0 and that didn't help either.

I expect the background image to show across all the devices I deploy on.

This is how I am defining my image in my xaml page:

```
 <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image Source="Mop3.jpg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.4,1,0.3" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Spacing="10">
            <Label Text="Cleanliness" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Italic"></Label>
            <Label Text="Starts with us" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
            <Button x:Name="Learnbtn" Text="Learn more" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Purple" BorderColor="Purple" CornerRadius="40" BorderWidth="1"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="130" Clicked="GotoHowPage"></Button>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0.99,1,0.05" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                      Padding="0">
            <Button Text="Get Started" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" BorderRadius="5" Clicked="GotoBothPage"></Button>

        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

The Mop3.jpg is the image not showing on other real devices (Android 8.1 and below )

PS: I tried another image and turned out the same, I also created another page in the project and tried setting the image Control and background image property to some image and didn't work too. But worked well when I created a new project and deployed to these devices so I suspect it is something wrong with the current project.

Comment: Please share your code and this image, If you provide these things, I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I Updated my question and added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to it.. it turned out the image I was using is large in size and in dimension too and couldn't display properly on Android 8.1 and lower. So I compressed the image at tinypng.com and re added to the drawable folder and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to mark your answer after two days, it will help others who have similar issue.